# php count function returns must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, count, countable

I have an array shown below and this line in my php controller:

```
 if(count($crew_rows != 0)){
```

Bluehost upgraded to php7.2 and I now get the following error:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home2/sailwbob/public_html/skipper/public/crew.php on line 1885
```

How do I fix this? (without reverting to an earlier version of php)

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 1
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => IN
                    [status] => OPEN
                    [avalstart] => 09:00:00
                    [avalend] => 21:00:00
                    [sort] => 0
                    [ssort] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 32
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => IN
                    [status] => OPEN
                    [avalstart] => 10:00:00
                    [avalend] => 20:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 76
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => IN
                    [status] => OPEN
                    [avalstart] => 09:00:00
                    [avalend] => 21:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 152
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => IN
                    [status] => OPEN
                    [avalstart] => 09:00:00
                    [avalend] => 21:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 155
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => IN
                    [status] => OPEN
                    [avalstart] => 11:30:00
                    [avalend] => 21:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 74
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => IN
                    [status] => OPEN
                    [avalstart] => 10:00:00
                    [avalend] => 18:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 25
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 35
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 59
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 69
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 126
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 133
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 153
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-17
                    [usr] => 161
                    [skipUsr] => 1
                    [user] => 
                    [crew] => OUT
                    [status] => OUT
                    [avalstart] => 00:00:00
                    [avalend] => 00:00:00
                    [sort] => 9
                    [ssort] => 9
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Move the comparision outside of the function call. Or remove it alltogether, 0 is falsey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the closing parenthesis in the wrong place in your `if` statement. It should look like this:

```php
if (count($crew_rows) != 0) {
```

Right now, you're passing the result of `$crew_rows != 0` to the `count()` function - a boolean, rather than an array.

Comment: Even not neccessary to compare at all. If count() is > 0, the expression is true. `if (count($crew_rows)) { ... }`.

Comment: @Alex P, thanks.  Thats be in my code for 5 years and this is the first time I got an error warning!